# Session expire on recieving POST request from other Domain

Tags: laravel

Laravel Version: 8.40
PHP Version: 7.3
Database Driver & Version: MySQL

Most payment processor sends callback to requested URL using POST method. When Laravel receives POST request from "other domain" it accepts the request (as the URL is excluded in VerifyCsrfToken), but the issue is my user gets logged out.

Why is this happening ?

In previous version of Laravel it works without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should add your callback routes in ***routes/api.php*** file... Because all routes in ***routes/web.php*** under web middleware (middleware controls VerifyCsrfToken for POST requests).

Comment: But the routes in question are excluded from CSRF Verification.

Comment: Moving things to API side works, but why is this happening in web middleware ?

Comment: All POST request in WEB middleware are in CSRF Verification

Comment: Then, when we exclude routes from CSRF verification, what happens? Don't take this the wrong way, just trying to understand the process.

Comment: Should be same.... Should work when we exclude routes from web middleware

Comment: That's the thing it does not work, when excluded its clears session and when not excluded it throws 419. It's a bit confusing.